# I have grid view and I assign the column value to date time picker with custom format but it is not working

Tags: c#

How to assign data grid view data to date time picker with custom format? The format is "ddd-MM-yy", C# winforms, this is my code.

```
string recievingDate = dgInvoice.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
txtRecievedDate.Text = recievingDate;
```

It works for default value and for the custom format.

Comment: Please first read up on how to ask a good question. As of now it is not even remotely clear what exactly you are asking for. Also don't use the title as a part of the question but to summarize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
txtRecievedDate.Text = string.Format("0:ddd-MM-yy", recievingDate);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: not its not working the same error, "string was not recognized as a valid date time"